# Module build failed: Support for the experimental syntax 'jsx' isn't currently enabled. Babel Issue with npm package I created

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, babeljs

I am working on implementing an npm package that will be shared between a few teams. The package is called `shared_header`. `shared-header` will be imported and used in my working project, `pricing-project`.

When I import `shared-header` and try to access it's components, I get the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: C:\Users\Q\pricing-project\node_modules\shared-header\src\components\header\Header.js: Support for the experimental syntax 'jsx' isn't currently enabled (142:7):

Add @babel/preset-react (https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/main/packages/babel-preset-react) to the 'presets' section of your Babel config to enable transformation.
If you want to leave it as-is, add @babel/plugin-syntax-jsx (https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/main/packages/babel-plugin-syntax-jsx) to the 'plugins' section to enable parsing.
```

## **pricing-project**

I have tried making the change that the error message suggests.
This is what my package.json file looks like inside `pricing-project`

`package.json (pricing-project):`

```
{
  "name": "pricing-project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "local": "SET REACT_APP_ENV=local&&react-scripts start",
    "mock": "SET REACT_APP_ENV=mock&&react-scripts start",
    "dev": "SET REACT_APP_ENV=dev&&react-scripts start http://localhost:3000/",
    "test": "SET REACT_APP_ENV=test&&npx react-scripts test --watchAll",
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@azure/msal-browser": "^2.31.0",
    "@azure/msal-react": "^1.4.10",
    "@emotion/cache": "^11.5.0",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.5.0",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.3.0",
    "@fullcalendar/core": "^5.10.1",
    "@fullcalendar/daygrid": "^5.10.1",
    "@fullcalendar/interaction": "^5.10.1",
    "@fullcalendar/list": "^5.10.1",
    "@fullcalendar/react": "^5.10.1",
    "@fullcalendar/timegrid": "^5.10.1",
    "@fullcalendar/timeline": "^5.10.1",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.5.0",
    "@mui/lab": "5.0.0-alpha.53",
    "@mui/material": "^5.9",
    "@mui/styles": "^5.9",
    "@mui/system": "^5.9",
    "@mui/x-data-grid": "^5.5.1",
    "@react-pdf/renderer": "^1.6.17",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.6.2",
    "apexcharts": "^3.29.0",
    "shared-header": "^1.2.0",
    "axios": "^0.24.0",
    "axios-retry": "^3.2.4",
    "date-fns": "^2.25.0",
    "downshift": "^6.1.12",
    "draft-js": "^0.11.7",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "formik": "^2.2.7",
    "gray-matter": "^4.0.3",
    "history": "^5.2.0",
    "i18next": "^21.6.16",
    "i18next-browser-languagedetector": "^6.1.4",
    "i18next-http-backend": "^1.4.0",
    "install": "^0.13.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "js-file-download": "^0.4.12",
    "jsdom": "^19.0.0",
    "loadcss": "0.0.2",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "msw": "^0.36.7",
    "nprogress": "^0.2.0",
    "numeral": "^2.0.6",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-apexcharts": "^1.3.9",
    "react-beautiful-dnd": "^13.0.0",
    "react-csv": "^2.0.3",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-draft-wysiwyg": "^1.14.5",
    "react-dropzone": "^11.4.2",
    "react-helmet-async": "^1.0.7",
    "react-hot-toast": "^1.0.2",
    "react-i18next": "^11.16.7",
    "react-icons": "^4.3.1",
    "react-idle-timer": "^4.6.4",
    "react-images": "^1.2.0-beta.7",
    "react-json-to-excel": "^1.0.7",
    "react-loading": "^2.0.3",
    "react-markdown": "^5.0.3",
    "react-minimal-pie-chart": "^8.2.0",
    "react-modal-image": "^2.5.0",
    "react-multi-select-component": "^4.1.13",
    "react-number-format": "^4.7.3",
    "react-perfect-scrollbar": "^1.5.8",
    "react-photo-gallery": "^8.0.0",
    "react-quill": "^1.3.5",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.6",
    "react-responsive-carousel": "^3.2.22",
    "react-router": "^6.0.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "react-swipeable-views": "^0.14.0",
    "react-swipeable-views-utils": "^0.14.0",
    "react-use-file-upload": "^0.9.5",
    "react-virtualized": "^9.22.3",
    "recharts": "^2.1.14",
    "redux": "^4.1.2",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.9",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.4.0",
    "sass": "^1.43.4",
    "stylis": "^4.0.10",
    "stylis-plugin-rtl": "^2.1.1",
    "swiper": "^6.8.4",
    "xlsx": "^0.18.5",
    "yup": "^0.32.11"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.16.0",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.16.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.18.6",
    "@testing-library/dom": "^8.11.2",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.48.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.48.2",
    "eslint": "^7.27.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.25.2",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.4.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.26.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.2.0",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5"
  },
  "optionalDependencies": {
    "fsevents": "^2.3.2"
  }
}
```

Inside `pricing-project`, I also have a `babel.config.json:`

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-react",
              "@babel/preset-typescript"],
 "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-syntax-jsx"]
}
```

## **shared-header**

Here is my `package.json` file from `shared-header`:

```
{
  "name": "shared-header",
  "version": "1.2.0",
  "description": "Header component to be shared between teams",
  "scripts": {
    "local": "SET REACT_APP_ENV=local&&react-scripts start",
    "mock": "SET REACT_APP_ENV=mock&&react-scripts start",
    "dev": "SET REACT_APP_ENV=dev&&react-scripts start http://localhost:3000/",
    "test": "SET REACT_APP_ENV=test&&npx react-scripts test --watchAll",
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "author": "John Smith",
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "@babel/preset-react",
      "@babel/preset-env",
      "@babel/preset-typescript"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@azure/msal-browser": "^2.34.0",
    "@azure/msal-react": "^1.5.4",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.10.6",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.6",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.11.11",
    "@mui/lab": "^5.0.0-alpha.124",
    "@mui/material": "^5.11.15",
    "@mui/styles": "^5.11.13",
    "@mui/x-date-pickers": "^6.0.3",
    "axios": "^1.3.4",
    "axios-retry": "^3.4.0",
    "date-fns": "^2.29.3",
    "i18next": "^22.4.13",
    "nprogress": "^0.2.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-draft-wysiwyg": "^1.15.0",
    "react-helmet-async": "^1.3.0",
    "react-i18next": "^12.2.0",
    "react-idle-timer": "^5.5.3",
    "react-perfect-scrollbar": "^1.5.8",
    "react-quill": "^2.0.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.9.0",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "react-use-file-upload": "^0.9.5",
    "sass": "^1.60.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.21.0",
    "@babel/core": "^7.21.4",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.21.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.21.4",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.18.6",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.21.4",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.59.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.59.1",
    "eslint": "^8.39.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^19.0.4",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.27.5",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.7.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.32.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "typescript": "^5.0.4"
  },
  "optionalDependencies": {
    "fsevents": "^2.3.2"
  }
}
```

I don't have a `babel.config.json` file in `shared-header`, but I do have the presets in the `package.json` file. I have tried using a `babel.config.json` file in `shared-header`, but the error persists.

I have tried all sorts of different combinations of configs and presets, and nothing has worked. How can I use the npm package I created (`shared-header`) within my working project (`pricing-project`) without getting the error above?

I'm also confused on if I should be making these changes to the npm module `shared-header` or the working project `pricing-project`

Side note: both projects use react-scripts, which is bundled with webpack under the hood. Could it be an issue with my webpack config?